# DIV "background-image" not stretched over entire DIV when using "background-size : 100% 100%"

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my website I am building a custom [HSV Color picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0aps.png).
Instead of using Gradients I've decided to opt for a .SVG Gradient image that I will use in my HSV Slider.

I am having a problem with the fitting of that Image into the Background of my DIV.

[Here's an example](https://imgur.com/a/346pWKL).
The Image is fitted perfectly in both Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer, but in Edge it looks as if only the "height" is at a "100%", and the "width" is "auto" - Which it is not, at least not in the CSS:

```
#pvdivsliderhue {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;
width: auto;
height: 30px;
border-radius: 15px;
background-image: url('images/pvhue.svg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-color: green;
display: flex;
}
```

How would I go about solving this issue?

Appreciate all the help!

Comment: Could you upload phvue.svg to imgur and send the html too please?

Comment: Yes of course, I don't see what help it could offer you, but if you're simply going after the image you can download it from [over here](https://www.mediafire.com/view/5kx6gjxwcu07dqp/pvhue.svg/file).

Comment: It probably has to do with the svg. It should work if you convert the pvhue.svg to a jpg or something. like [here](https://codepen.io/evochrome/pen/LMMbpV)

Comment: Spot on, after converting the .SVG to .PNG all works well. Hate that there is such limited support for vectors to this day, especially since they scale so well! If you want to post an official answer I'll accept it as the solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is still buggy in Edge. Therefore, I advise to use old school .png or .jpg images if you don't require a vector image.

Check out the working example:

```css
/* Demo Styles */
.picker {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

/* Hue Slider */
#pvdivsliderhue {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Hue_alpha.png/900px-Hue_alpha.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="picker">
  <div id="pvdivsliderhue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `margins` and `padding` 0

```
#pvdivsliderhue {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;
width: auto;
height: 30px;
border-radius: 15px;
background-image: url('images/pvhue.svg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-color: green;
display: flex;
margin :0;
padding :0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already defined those two in the parent DIV's, but I've still tried it... Unfortunately, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try `background-size: cover` or `background-size: container`. I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I have tried "background-size : contain" before and [it doesn't work as intended](https://imgur.com/a/5X66bxD)...

Comment: "background-size: cover" at first glance appears to be the solution - But it doesn't scale. [Here are examples of full screen Width and reduced Width](https://imgur.com/a/KpYGNtq)